# What would be the the best way to make multiple instances of a class when a program runs?

Tags: python

I am making a pokemon text based game. Each different species is a separate object. My whole question is how would the wild pokemon work? Due to the fact that wild pokemon are encountered randomly how would a new instance of this pokemon object work? I was thinking of using a temporary variable, however, the problem is this object needs to be referenced later because the user has a choice to catch the pokemon and use it.

Example:

```
class pokemon(object):
    pass
class Charmander(pokemon):
    pass
encounterChance = random.randint(1,10)
if encounterChance <6:
   #create new object here and battle
```

Since there will be multiple encounters it feels inefficient to track every encounter and whether or not the user caught the pokemon. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `class Charmander(pokemon):`?

Comment: Are you asking how to select the pokemon species dynamically?

Comment: oops yes you are right

Comment: @Barmar i guess in a way yes dynamically, however i know this causes a lot of problems and I just want to know any alternatives if possible

Comment: Put all the classes in a list, then select a list element randomly and construct it.

Comment: Or in your case, just something like `if encounterChance < 6: obj = Charmander() else: obj = SomethingElse()`

Comment: @Barmar since there is no set number of times an encounter would happen. Would the only way to solve this problem be to dynamically create new instances?

Comment: Put them in a list?

Comment: @Barmar I understand the list aspect. Let's say that a player experiences 5 encounters however, when the player looks for pokemon again they experience 6 encounters. How would i go about making new pokemon for each encounter? Because i don't want to set a limit on the amount of encounters possible and it overall just seems inefficient.

Comment: Every time you have an encounter, you create the new pokemon and append it to the list of all pokemons.

Comment: @Barmar How would this be done though? Thats what im having trouble understanding. Essentially when the player looks for pokemon they would have an infinite number of times they can encounter pokemon. (This is because the encounter is a "game mode" essentially where they keep encountering new wild pokemon)

Comment: `new_pokemon = <code to create random character>` then `all_pokemon.append(new_pokemon)`. Now `all_pokemon` contains the potentially infinite list of all pokemon.